# Prevent overlapping times in start-time, end-time columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraints

We have a use case where we are storing start_week and end_week in a row and want to make sure that these values across rows are never overlapping i.e. they are exclusive. Examples below

```
Ideal
code - startw - endw
T1 - 201401 - 201404
T2 - 201405 - 201408
T3 - 201409 - 201416

Not Ideal
code - startw - endw
T1 - 201401 - 201404
T2 - 201403 - 201408
T3 - 201407 - 201408
T3 - 201406 - 201410
```

Can such a constraint be added in Postgres so errors are caught during insertion? What would be the best approach to tackle such an problem and avoid insertions rather than running checks after data is inserted.

Comment: It's best not to store timestamps/dates like that. Just store the date and format them to week numbers on output with `to_char`. If you *must* store "year" and "week", use separate columns. It makes this sort of thing much uglier.

Comment: Side issue: If you have to do any sort of arithmetic on those dates, I'd store them as either a date field containing the date of the first day of the appropriate week, or an integer indicating the number of weeks since some starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a feature designed for exactly this - [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION).

See [`CREATE TABLE ... EXCLUDE ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE).

For your purposes you want a [constraint on a range](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT). The case you have is covered in the manual.

It's somewhat complicated by your use of a weird format for your dates; you'll need to convert them to a tstzrange for the exclusion constraint.

```
create table exclude(code text, startw integer, endw integer);

insert into exclude(code, startw, endw) values
('T1', 201401, 201404),
('T2', 201405, 201408),
('T3', 201409, 201416);
```

You can't just:

```
alter table exclude 
  add constraint no_overlapping_timestamps 
  EXCLUDE USING gist( tstzrange(startw, endw) WITH && );
```

because you aren't using real timestamps; you have to convert your week numbers to timestamps in the expression above. I can't do that for you because I don't know how you define "week". If it's the standard way, then:

```
alter table exclude 
  add constraint no_overlapping_timestamps 
  EXCLUDE USING gist( tstzrange(to_date(startw, 'YYYYWW'), to_date(endw, 'YYYYWW')) WITH && );
```

Comment: Craig thanks for the quick reply and pointer to exclusion constraints. Very helpful. I might be able to break year and week numbers to make this easier like you said.